# Change color of PowerShell 7 Get-ChildItem result

Tags: windows-10, powershell, pycharm, powershell-7.0

I am using PowerShell 7 as terminal in PyCharm and the default colors for the commands were not really clear.

I created a `profile.ps1` where I set them in this way:

```
# Set colours
Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors @{
    Command = "`e[30;107m"
    Comment = "`e[32;107m"
    ContinuationPrompt = "`e[30;47m"
    Emphasis = "`e[30;107m"
    Error = "`e[91;47m"
    InlinePrediction = "`e[90;47m"
    Keyword = "`e[92;47m"
    ListPrediction = "`e[33;47m"
    ListPredictionSelected = "`e[48;5;238m"
    Member = "`e[97;47m"
    Number = "`e[30;47m"
    Operator ="`e[90;47m"
    Parameter = "`e[90;47m"
    Selection = "`e[30;107m"
    String = "`e[36;47m"
    Type = "`e[30;47m"
    Variable =  "`e[92;47m"
}
```

but I couldn't find how to modify the `Get-ChildItem` result for the directory.
As I am using a light theme, [the result is not really clear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2r3o.png).

Looking around it seems there are some solutions using a third-party command or complicated scripts, but I am wondering if in PowerShell 7 there is an easy way to do it with a command as `Set-PSReadLineOption`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does [Change PowerShell console syntax highlighting colors of PSReadLine – 4sysops](https://4sysops.com/wiki/change-powershell-console-syntax-highlighting-colors-of-psreadline/) answer your question?

Comment: @DavidPostill it seems the page is not available any more

Comment: https://4sysops.com/wiki/change-powershell-console-syntax-highlighting-colors-of-psreadline/

Comment: sorry @DavidPostill but I continue to obtain the **Error 404 - Page not found** error, at this point I think it's my problem, but I don't understand which problem I could have... so strange

Comment: @DavidPostill could you please just copy and past here the commands? Thanks a lot

Comment: Sorry, don't have the time for that.

Comment: Finally I managed to open that page, unfortunately it didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colour support for the output of Get-ChildItem was included in [PR#14403](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/14403) and released to [v7.2.0](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/tag/v7.2.0).

It is configurable via the [`$PSStyle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?#psstyle) preference variable.

You should put any changes into your [`$PROFILE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles)— as you've been doing— but you'll need to modify `$PSStyle`, not the PSReadLine options.

From the documentation:

> `$PSStyle.FileInfo` is a nested object to control the coloring of
> FileInfo objects.
>
> - **Directory** - Built-in member to specify color for directories
> - **SymbolicLink** - Built-in member to specify color for symbolic links
> - **Executable** - Built-in member to specify color for executables.
> - **Extension** - Use this member to define colors for different file
>   extensions. The Extension member pre-includes extensions for archive
>   and PowerShell files.  Note
>
> > **NOTE**   `$PSStyle.FileInfo` is only available when the `PSAnsiRenderingFileInfo` experimental feature is enabled. For more
> > information, see [about_Experimental_Features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_experimental_features) and [Using
> > experimental features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/powershell/scripting/learn/experimental-features).
> >
> > In PowerShell 7.3, the `PSAnsiRenderingFileInfo` feature became
> > mainstream and available by default.

So to change file and directory colours, set the appropriate property in the [`$PSStyle.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psstyle.fileinfoformatting) object to the ANSI escape sequence representing the colour of your choice.

For example, to change the colour of directories to bright yellow:

```
# As separate Yellow and Bold attributes
$PSStyle.FileInfo.Directory = "`e[33;1m" # Note the double quotes!

# Sequences 90-97 and 100-107 are also supported
$PSStyle.FileInfo.Directory = "`e[93m" # Note the double quotes!
```

The double quotes are essential, since otherwise `` ​`e `` will be interpreted literally, and you'll get a `SetValueIncovationException` error.

Whilst the documentation claims that 24-bit colour is also supported via the `FromRgb` method, that method is only available on the foreground and background colour styles (I'm not allowed to link to both classes' SDK documentation directly, since I'm at the hyperlink limit, so here's the SDK doc for [`System.Management.Automation.PSStyle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psstyle)).

Comment: thanks, I think combine `PSStyle` and `Set-PSReadLineOption` I can obtain what I want.

Comment: Yes, `Set-PSReadLineOption` works for your shell input, and `$PSStyle` works for the output. The change to results from directory listings (`Get-ChildItem`) surprised me too, but luckily it came immediately after I upgraded to PS7.3.1 so I knew where to look to find the cause. It wasn't properly mentioned in the release notes.